# URI vs File performance

Tags: java, android, performance, file, uri

I have been working with files a lot lately. I was wondering what is the difference between URI and File. Basically in the code:

```
  List<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Uri uri : uris
            ) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath());
    }

    for (File file : listOfImageFiles
            ) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
}
```

Which is faster? And which is recommended to use? I need it for geting their paths on the storage, and later saving those paths to Strings.

Comment: `getPath()` on a `Uri` is only useful if the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`. Otherwise, `getPath()` is meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speed difference in negligible compared to the time spent reading data from disk-  the difference will be in nanoseconds where reading the data takes milliseconds.  The reason you'd use a URI rather than a file is if you're representing data that may not be on the filesystem-  it may belong to a ContentProvider or exist on a remote server.  If that may be the case, use a URI.  If you know that isn't the case, use a File.